# Jenkins Pipeline: running steps on different docker host

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have just set up docker build slaves on my jenkins server according to [this article](https://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/) to move away for static build nodes.

I have run into a minor issue. I use bitbucket and [bcbsn](https://github.com/030/bcbsn) to update the build status. I'd prefer not to install go and maintain that in all my build slaves, so I considerd using the docker image from bcbsn like this

```bash
docker run utrecht/bcbsn:2.0.4 -clientID ${clientID} -clientSecret ${clientSecret} -state FAILED -commit ${env.GIT_COMMIT} -name ${buildName} -repoSlug talentindicator -owner talentinsights -url ${env.JOB_URL} -key ${buildName}
```

I have read through this article on running [docker inside docker](https://devopscube.com/run-docker-in-docker/) and all the pros and cons, coming to the conclusion that I would prefer not to go this way.

Therefore I would like that to run either on the main node or just on the docker host I have set up for the build slaves. Is this possible? And if so, how to do it?

### my own attempt

```
stages {
        stage ('Staging'){
            steps {
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '6eab2fcc-7703-4d92-9e7d-120d66f771b3  ', usernameVariable: 'clientID', passwordVariable: 'clientSecret')]) {
                    docker.withServer('tcp://192.168.0.247:4243') {
                        docker.image('utrecht/bcbsn:2.0.4').withRun("-clientID ${clientID} -clientSecret ${clientSecret} -state INPROGRESS -commit ${env.GIT_COMMIT} -name ${buildName} -repoSlug talentindicator -owner talentinsights -url ${env.JOB_URL} -key ${buildName}") {
                            /* do nothing */
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

this results in

> `Method calls on objects not allowed outside "script" blocks.`

### Snippets from my Pipeline where I use bcbsn:

#### in my initial build step:

```
stages {
        stage ('Staging'){
            steps {
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', usernameVariable: 'clientID', passwordVariable: 'clientSecret')]) {
                    sh "docker run utrecht/bcbsn:2.0.4 -clientID ${clientID} -clientSecret ${clientSecret} -state INPROGRESS -commit ${env.GIT_COMMIT} -name ${buildName} -repoSlug talentindicator -owner talentinsights -url ${env.JOB_URL} -key ${buildName}"
                }
           }
     }
```

#### And in my post section:

```
post {
        //https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/
        changed {
            script {
                hasChanged = true
            }
        }
        success {
            script {
                if(hasChanged){
                    echo '************** First success in a while! '
                }
            }
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', usernameVariable: 'clientID', passwordVariable: 'clientSecret')]) {
                    sh "docker run utrecht/bcbsn:2.0.4 -clientID ${clientID} -clientSecret ${clientSecret} -state SUCCESSFUL -commit ${env.GIT_COMMIT} -name ${buildName} -repoSlug talentindicator -owner talentinsights -url ${env.JOB_URL} -key ${buildName}"
                }
        }
        failure {
            script {
                if(hasChanged){
                    echo '************** Build broke '
                }
            }
            echo "Setting build status in Bitbucket"
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', usernameVariable: 'clientID', passwordVariable: 'clientSecret')]) {
                    sh "docker run utrecht/bcbsn:2.0.4 -clientID ${clientID} -clientSecret ${clientSecret} -state FAILED -commit ${env.GIT_COMMIT} -name ${buildName} -repoSlug talentindicator -owner talentinsights -url ${env.JOB_URL} -key ${buildName}"
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the global variable methods that interact with the Jenkins Pipeline plugin for Docker classes, then you need to nested those inside `script` blocks when using declarative pipeline syntax:

```
stage ('Staging'){
  steps {
    script {
      withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '6eab2fcc-7703-4d92-9e7d-120d66f771b3  ', usernameVariable: 'clientID', passwordVariable: 'clientSecret')]) {
        docker.withServer('tcp://192.168.0.247:4243') {
          docker.image('utrecht/bcbsn:2.0.4').withRun("-clientID ${clientID} -clientSecret ${clientSecret} -state INPROGRESS -commit ${env.GIT_COMMIT} -name ${buildName} -repoSlug talentindicator -owner talentinsights -url ${env.JOB_URL} -key ${buildName}") {
            /* do nothing */
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```